# Why does the query not return any data?

Tags: sql

I want to retract objects within the dates

Here are all the objects:

[image]

And here is the query:

[image]

However, if I change the last date to '2020-10-10' everything works

Comment: Im taking a guess here but is whats saved in the same datetime format e.g. yyyy-mm-dd and maybe what you looking up is yyyy-dd-mm?

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  If you execute `DBCC USEROPTIONS`, what is the `DATEFORMAT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the data type of the column StartDateTime? If it's datetime, your where clause needs to look like this

```
WHERE StartDateTime Between Convert(datetime, '2020-09-01', 120) 
      And Convert(datetime, '2020-10-01', 120)
```